# .NET Angular how to get data asynchronously

Tags: javascript, c#, angular, typescript

First I'm trying to get all projects from the database by given **userId** from URL. I'm doing it in ngOnInit(). Each project has it's field **Languages** which is a list of objects from another table Languages. One record in this table has a field named **projectId** by which I'm trying to get all languages for each project. I think I have a problem with receiving data asynchronously because projects are received properly but **languages** field in each Project object is null. What should I do?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.userId = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    this.getAllProjectsByUserId(this.userId);
    this.getLanguagesByProjectId();
  }

  getAllProjectsByUserId(id: number) {  //receivng all projects for given userId
    this.portfolioAppService.getAllProjectsByUserId(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.projectsList = data;
      console.log(this.projectsList);
    },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }

  getLanguagesByProjectId() {  //receiving all languages for each project
    this.projectsList.forEach(x => {
      this.portfolioAppService.getLanguagesByProjectId(x.id).subscribe((data) => {
        x.languages = data;
        console.log(this.projectsList);
      },
        error => console.error(error)
      );
    });
  }
```

Comment: Async means, that you don't know when wich data arrives. But you call it like it would arrive in order. Your second call depends on the first one. But you can't be sure wich one will arrive first. So you either nest the subscriptions and call them inside the subscribe or you use a MergeMap from RxJS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the call to `getLanguagesByProjectId()` to when the projects have been received:

```
  getAllProjectsByUserId(id: number) {  //receiving all projects for given userId
    this.portfolioAppService.getAllProjectsByUserId(id).subscribe((data) => {
      this.projectsList = data;
      console.log(this.projectsList);
      this.getLanguagesByProjectId();
    },
      error => console.error(error)
    );
  }
```

As otherwise `this.projectsList` property has not the needed values yet.